# MySQL 5.6 is faster than MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running one query which is faster on MySQL5.6 than MySQL8. It takes around 4 seconds in MySQL5.6 whereas takes 32 secs in MySQL8. As per MySQL documentation MySQL8 is faster but I have seen the opposite case.

Query:

```
select id 
from defaultitem 
where masterId='3b1e9726-12ea-4adf-a6ef-f0950075fec4' 
and mainID in ( 
    select id 
    from campaign 
    where deleteflag=0 
    and validflag=1 
    and deptid='9d9d7e0f-7256-4ac6-9398-378ae9a0239e')
```

Show create table:

```
defaultitem - CREATE TABLE `defaultitem` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `masterId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK22505D768EC27364` (`masterId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK22505D768EC27364` FOREIGN KEY (`masterId`) REFERENCES `combomaster` (`masterid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

campaign - CREATE TABLE `campaign` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deptid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleteflag` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `validflag` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK47DDEA51F157E732` (`deptid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK47DDEA51F157E732` FOREIGN KEY (`deptid`) REFERENCES `dept` (`deptid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


EXPLAIN query in MySQL5.6 - 
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | defaultitem | ref    | FK22505D768EC27364         | FK22505D768EC27364 | 768     | const                             | 812528 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | campaign      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK47DDEA51F157E732 | PRIMARY            | 767     | db.defaultitem.mainID |      1 | Using where                        |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+


EXPLAIN QUERY in MySQL8 -
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | campaign      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,FK47DDEA51F157E732 | FK47DDEA51F157E732 | 768     | const |     15 |     1.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | defaultitem | NULL       | ref  | FK22505D768EC27364         | FK22505D768EC27364 | 768     | const | 787517 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

innodb_buffer_pool_size is same in both versions.

I assumed that MySQL 8 would be faster.

Comment: And your question is? I don't think comparing performance between different versions of MySql is a relevant topic for stackoverflow so perhaps you can be more specific in what your issue is?

Comment: Is it the same explain plan after an [analyze table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) on both tables?

Comment: Why not go with a faster query?

Comment: Overall MySQL 8 is faster than 5.6. They cannot guarantee that every single query is faster (or even as fast as before). For your query you may consider providing composite indexes: `campaign (deptid, deleteflag, validflag, id)`, `defaultitem (masterid, mainid)`, `defaultitem (mainid, masterid)`. That goes for both DBMS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is functionally identical to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.id  
  FROM defaultitem x
  JOIN campaign y
    ON y.id = x.mainid
   AND y.deleteflag = 0 
   AND y.validflag = 1 
   AND y.deptid = '9d9d7e0f-7256-4ac6-9398-378ae9a0239e'
 WHERE x.masterId = '3b1e9726-12ea-4adf-a6ef-f0950075fec4';
```

...so why not write it that way.

A key on some combination of (deptid,validflag,deleteflag) would probably help.

Comment: I like the original query much better, because it puts criteria in the `WHERE` clause where it belongs in my opinion.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I like this because if you change to an outer join, you only have to amend one thing - but horses for courses

Comment: A `JOIN` could return the same defaultitem.id more than once, when the defaultitem can be joined to multiple campaigns.  While by using an `IN` it wouldn't.  So I wouldn't call that "functionally identical". :) An `EXISTS` would be, but doesn't garantee a better execution plan.

Comment: I have got this query corrected by adding more more join, but that is not my concern. My concern is that we have 10 products using MySQL5.6 and now we are upgrading to MySQL8, such kind of extreme slowness can still be encountered in some cases which get exposed by client. So in case there is any configuration which can be done to avoid such scenario that would be great.

Comment: I just find it implausible that the above query takes as long as 4 seconds on an indexed data set.

Comment: Yes it is taking that much time, there are total 17lakh records in table defaultitem